# Why does google add "GitHib pages" to search resuls title instead of using document's title?

Tags: seo, github

I tried to search my github pages. The title of index page on my pages is "LoL AutoClient", but on google, I get this:

[image: image description]

Note that instead of document title, the path `auto-client` is used for some reason. Does this happen to all github pages? Can I force to display more informative title for people who search for the page?

Comment: Shows up fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you search

> site:http://darker.github.io

in Google it will show properly. Why it is showing Auto-client in general search is, that text "auto client" is H1 and many headings consists of word "auto", and also the text "LOL league of legends" is not optimized properly.

It is the crawler's tendency to assume proper heading and serve. In this case it took "Auto Client". If you have the control over the source code, you can optimize better or do better off-page optimization to make the better statement by giving anchor texts with that keyword "LOL league of legends". I believe proper on-page optimization is sufficient.